# Anyone know of a good composite number counter?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am looking for a chart that would show how many composite numbers there are under "n" broken out by how many factors they have. Has anyone seen a chart like this?

Example information I am looking for:

composite numbers under 20

total: 11

with 2 factors: 6

with 3 factors: 4

with 4 factors: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn to program the computer.  It takes only a few minutes to get a computer to emit such a table. (Actually producing the table is instantaneous.)

I tabulated it up to $N=1000$ and put it [here](http://plover.com/~mjd/misc/math/factor-table.txt) for you.  (The table is too large for a SE post.)  Notice line $20$, which reads $8\,6\,4\,1$, as you requested.

Comment: I don't know how to program a computer, could you run n=1,000,000?

Comment: Okay, it's [here](http://plover.com/~mjd/misc/math/factor-table.txt.gz). The rightmost column is a catchall for numbers with 12 or more factors.  You will need to use `gzip` or some equivalent to uncompress the file.